# Deep Learning Caffe Save Test output labels

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I'm wondering how I can save in Caffe the output of testing results (predicted labels) in a file?

In addition to averaged accuracy reported by Caffe on the screen, I'd like to take a look at the labels in detail.

Thank you,
Saman

Answer (score 2):

@Saman - I would suggest you to use the original version of Caffe which is designed for Linux . As they have mentioned in their website, the Windows version is unofficial. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Caffe offers a [`"HDF5Output"`](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers.html) layer that can save to hdf5 binary file the outputs of certain layers.
You can see the [header file](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/include/caffe/layers/hdf5_output_layer.hpp) for more information.

Comment: Dear Shai, I was aware of this module before posting my questions here. That is not working. I was hoping someone who could successfully run it , can reply my question.

Comment: @Saman what do you mean by "not working"? what have you tried? please post what you have done and what is not working and you might get a more concrete answer.

Comment: I'm wondering if anybody could successfully run HDF5Output using any 3rd party Windows Caffe ?

Comment: @Saman are you using caffe on windows? you should state this in your question: where did you get this build? is it compiled with hdf5 support?

Comment: I have been using the Caffe Windows Master [link](https://github.com/happynear/caffe-windows) and it seems HDF5Output capability is not compiled and used in this version. I will check the original Linux Caffe version.